# JavaFx .jar file not running correctly

Tags: java, javafx

Im developing an application using javafx, and it works fine when running from net beans, but when i try to run the application through the .jar file,the application starts and i´m able to use some of its functionalities, but not all of them.

When it starts always gives me this error:

[image]

This is the a part code :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

    bd=new BD();
    bd.iniciarConexao();


    stage= primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle("Gestão de eventos - AAC");

    layerPane = new StackPane();
    initRoot();

    scene = new Scene(layerPane, 1020, 700);
    scene.getStylesheets().addAll(ProjectV2.class.getResource("ProjectV2.css").toExternalForm(),
    ProjectV2.class.getResource("calendarstyle.css").toExternalForm());




    //MainToolBar-----------------------------------------------------------
    nomeAplicacao = new Label("Gestão de eventos - AAC");


    hbNomeAplicacao= new HBox();

    hbEmblemas = new HBox(40);

    emblemas = new ArrayList<>();

    toolBar = new ToolBar();


    logo = new ImageView(new Image(ProjectV2.class.getResourceAsStream("images/gestaoDeEventos2_2.png")));
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    spacer1= new Region();
    spacer2= new Region();
    spacer3= new Region();
    spacer4= new Region();


    centerPane= new BorderPane();

    paScrollPane= new ScrollPane();

    paVb= new VBox();
    paVb.setPrefHeight(500);
    hbSubtitulo= new HBox();
    subtitulo= new Label("Funcionalidades");
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    //LogToolBar------------------------------------------------------------
    logToolBar= new ToolBar();


    loginButton = new MenuButton();
    loginButton.setId("SettingsButton");   
    loginButton.setPopupSide(Side.TOP);    
    loginButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(ProjectV2.class.getResourceAsStream("images/business_user2.png"))));

    mLogin = MenuItemBuilder.create().text("Login").build();
    mAddFunc = MenuItemBuilder.create().text("Mudar password").build();
    mLogout = MenuItemBuilder.create().text("Logout").build();
    //mEditUser = MenuItemBuilder.create().text("Editar funcionário").build();
    mFactura= MenuItemBuilder.create().text("Factura").build();

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------


    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
    toogleMaximized();
}


public void toogleMaximized() 
{

    screen = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), 1, 1).get(0);

    if (maximized) 
    {
        maximized = false;
        if (backupWindowBounds != null) {
            stage.setX(backupWindowBounds.getMinX());
            stage.setY(backupWindowBounds.getMinY());
            stage.setWidth(backupWindowBounds.getWidth());
            stage.setHeight(backupWindowBounds.getHeight());
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        maximized = true;
        backupWindowBounds = new Rectangle2D(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
        stage.setX(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinX());
        stage.setY(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(screen.getVisualBounds().getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(screen.getVisualBounds().getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the corresponding code (start method of your ProjectV2.java file, around line 311).

Comment: Just added some of the code, hope it helps

Comment: its -> stage.show(); i cant get why it gives error running from jar, since it runs ok while using netbeans

Comment: It maybe because of the use of different versions of JavaFX. Write `System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());` then run from both Netbeans and command line. Is there any differences?

Comment: yes they're different. NetBeans displays ->2.2.3-b05. while in command line displays -> 8.0.0-ea-b100.  How can I change this ?

Comment: @cdn34. Call the java with its full path like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java ..." or change your "Environment variables" accordingly.